# why doesn't SPMetal generate Publishing Schedule columns?

Tags: linq, sharepoint, code-generation

Happy 2011 experts,,,

I have a sharepoint 2010 publishing site that I use SPMetal to generate classes to.
The problem is some fields doesn't get generated like:

PublishingStartDate and PublishingEndDate even though I tried using IncludeHiddenColumns and IncludeHiddenContentTypes parameters with no success.

Any clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, SPMetal generates code only for field types that ship with SharePoint Foundation 2010 (not Server 2010), which means some of the special field types used by publishing features in the server version are not included.

Workaround 1:
Extending SPMetal to cover scenarios like this — is to use the ICustomMapping interface to include extra fields in your LINQ model.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee538669.aspx

Workaround 2:
Check this SPMetal documentatin http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee535056.aspx and look at Column Elment section that explains how you can use the XML paramter file for SPMetal to add columns that were not generated.

http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/402f59d2-7365-4047-b194-057e84c0cf57/

Answer (score 1):

There are problems with some columns see: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sharepoint2010programming/thread/402f59d2-7365-4047-b194-057e84c0cf57/

Answer (score 0):

I had a problem where SPMetal was not generating a column for me, and the answer was that my list had come from a Content Type, but the column had been added separately. If a list comes from a Content Type, SPMetal only generates C# properties for columns that come from that Content Type.

For reference on all reasons why a column may not be generated:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee537010.aspx

look under "Properties That Represent List Columns"